# Scheduling Update by Query Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

We are running an ES index that is pushed a batch upload of data daily. The challenge, within the upload there are small pockets of bad data that we are manually updating through the Update by Query API. The Update Query is relatively simple and looks like this:

```
POST entity/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.index = '####'"
  },
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "match": { "location": "Random Location"}},
          {"query_string": {
            "default_field": "excerpt",
            "query": "Utah OR Ohio OR Chicago OR \"Logan, UT\" OR \"Logan, OH\" OR \"Logan square\" OR ((\"North Logan\" OR NorthLogan) AND (Utah OR UT)) OR \"logan airport\""
          }}
        ],
      "must_not": [
        {"term":{"index.raw": "####"}}
      ]
      }
    }
}
```

Every time we run the query, we are able to pull out the documents that have bad metadata. What I am wondering, is there a way to automate this query to run on a schedule. (somewhat similar to the [Watcher API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-api-put-watch.html) - but combined with the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query)). Any thoughts would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply running your update on cron or scheduled after each upload?

Comment: @Val - I've never set up a scheduled task with Chron. Would you happen to be able to provide what an example elastic query command would look like in Chron?

Comment: What I meant was simply to schedule a cron job that runs your update by query via [crontab](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html)